# how to access array position from string

Tags: php

I have a string containing an array key position which I am trying to use this position to access the array ($arr).

Example of string ($str) which has a string value of **svg.1.linearGradient.0.@style**

This would be the equivalent of `['svg'][1]['linearGradient'][0]['@style']`

How can I use the string to access/retrieve data from $arr using the above position?

For example, lets say i wanted to unset the array key `unset($arr['svg'][1]['linearGradient'][0]['@style'])` - how can i achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mechanism of passing the value by reference:

```
$result = &$arr;
$path = explode('.', $str);

for($i = 0; $i < count($path); $i++) {
    $key = $path[$i];
    if (is_array($result) && array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
        if ($i == count($path) - 1) {
            unset($result[$key]); // deleting an element with the last key 
        } else {
            $result = &$result[$key];
        }
    } else {
        break; // not found
    }
}

unset($result); // resetting value by reference

print_r($arr);
```

[fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8dea048ed85624bdf5d31c82bb035b6d0e0efbf2)

Comment: this looks great, thank you!

Comment: is there a way to get the original key value with this also if i want to set a new key with the same value ?

Comment: If you need to store the value before deleting it, just store it in another variable. If you need to replace a value, just assign a new one instead of unset `$result[$key] = 'new value';`. [updated fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15259ef93a8568901c8e09310565a879f0fe4c8c)

Comment: i would be grateful if you can update the fiddle to show a third option and to set value $result[$key] under a new key name in the same position of the array (lets call that @style2) `$arr['svg'][1]['linearGradient'][0][@style2]` .. unless of course there is another way to just replace the existing key name?

I would be looking at setting the new key with the value fore unsetting the old key

Comment: [fiddle](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15259ef93a8568901c8e09310565a879f0fe4c8c)

Comment: Legend. I have marked this as solution. thanks so much for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

One method could be to split the string on `.`, then iterate through the "keys" to traverse your `$arr` object. (Please excuse my poor php, it's been a while...)

Example:

```php
$arr = (object)[
    "svg" => (array)[
        (object)[],
        (object)[
            "linearGradient" => [
                (object)[
                    "@style" => "testing",
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$str = "svg.1.linearGradient.0.@style";
$keys = explode('.', $str);
$val = $arr;
foreach($keys as $key) {
  $val =  is_object($val) 
    ? $val->$key 
    : $val[$key];
}

echo $val;
```

https://3v4l.org/h8YPv

### Unsetting a key given the path:

```
$arr = (object)[
    "svg" => (array)[
        (object)[],
        (object)[
            "linearGradient" => [
                (object)[
                    "@style" => "testing",
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$str = "svg.1.linearGradient.0.@style";
$keys = explode('.', $str);
$exp = "\$arr";
$val = $arr;
foreach($keys as $index => $key) {
    $exp .=  is_object($val) 
        ? "->{'" . $key . "'}"
        : "[" . $key . "]";
    
    $val = is_object($val) ? $val->$key : $val[$key]; 
}

eval("unset($exp);");
```

https://3v4l.org/Fdo6B

### Docs

- [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: thanks, this allows me to access the array and return the value. What if i wanted to unset the key and its value? `unset($arr['svg'][1]['linearGradient'][0]['@style'])` ?

Comment: yes but the snippet only returns the key and value pair, i don't think i can unset it just with unset($key) .. i will need the path to the key also.

Comment: I have a solution to unset the key, but it's not ideal. Requires `eval()`...